# What is the name of a roof section between converging valleys?

Tags: roof, roofing, diverter

I have a similar situation as the member in this thread:

[How to flash a roof valley on parallel roofs](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/46096/how-to-flash-a-roof-valley-on-parallel-roofs?newreg=e15a283deefc4b9087ce04f4b58dd932)

However, I'd like to know if this roofing solution has a name. I'm thinking since it diverts rainwater, maybe it's called a diverter? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar to a [**cricket**](http://I%27t%20similar%20to%20a%20**cricket**%20but%20those%20are) but those are linguistically chained to diverting water on the upper side of a chimney, as far as I know - but I see the definition at wikipedia includes the language:

> or the transition from one roof area to another

So perhaps that, but the only thing I've ever heard a roofer refer to as a cricket is the one above a chimney. However, I have found a couple of other pages that support the more general use of the term *(which I'm not linking because they seem rather advertising/spam-like, but "**roof cricket**" will find you some examples. **Diverter** is listed as an alternate name, as is **saddle**.)*

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: It probably doesn't have a formal name because it's not special.

You rectify the problem of a horizontal valley by making it into two non-horizontal (sloped) valleys. You accomplish this by raising one end of the valley, which has the effect of *widening* the valley floor and sloping it. This, in turn, results in two valleys.

Call it a diverter if you like, but it really doesn't divert anything--the water ends up at the same place it would have, more or less. It's just another roof plane, really, equivalent to any other roof plane. It just happens to have converging valleys flanking it.

The same situation occurs between two dormers, for example:

[image]

<sub>[Image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iko.com%2Fna%2Fpro%2Fbuilding-professional-tools%2Froofing-101%2Fhow-to-install-roof-shingles-on-a-dormer%2F&psig=AOvVaw14V5QX0a8yjXbgvnMt-BO2&ust=1608323606298000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCKiGobzu1e0CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)</sub>